# Interrelated constraints via linear combinations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Given $x$ and $y$ are real variable such that:

$\left| x \right|\le \alpha ,\left| y \right|\le \alpha ,$

where $\alpha$ is a positive constant.
I want to determine bounds of $u,v$ where $u,v$ are determined by a combination of $x,y$ as follows:
\begin{align}
  & u\text{ }=\text{ }x\text{ }-\text{ }y, \\ 
 & v\text{ }=\text{ }y. \\ 
\end{align}
My approach is:
\begin{align}
  & -2\alpha\le u=x\text{ }-\text{ }y\le 2\alpha, \\ 
 & -\alpha\le v\text{ }=\text{ }y\le \alpha. \\ 
\end{align}
Therefore, the bounds of $u,v$ are :
$\left| u \right|\le 2\alpha ,\left| v \right|\le \alpha ,$

I tried to verify my result by transforming the original equation into:
\begin{align}
  & x\text{ }=\text{ }u\text{ }+\text{ }v, \\ 
 & y\text{ }=\text{ }v. \\ 
\end{align}

Then using the derived constraints, we can conclude
$\left| x \right|\le 3\alpha ,\left| y \right|\le \alpha ,$

which is different from the original statement.
Could you please help me to indicate where is my mistake? and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is a mistake.

The inequality system $\displaystyle \begin{cases}|ax+by|\le c \\|dx+ey|\le f \end{cases}$ (where $c,f>0$) defines a region in the shape of a parallelogram, with sides $ax+by=\pm c$ and $dx+ey=\pm f$.

The regions defined by  $\displaystyle \begin{cases}|x|\le k_1 \\|y|\le k_2 \end{cases}$ is a rectangle and The regions defined by  $\displaystyle \begin{cases}|u|\le k_3 \\|v|\le k_4 \end{cases}$  is a parallelogram with internal angles $45^\circ$ and $135^\circ$ in the $x$,$y$-plane.

Take $\alpha=2$. The region $\displaystyle \begin{cases}|x|\le 2 \\|y|\le 2 \end{cases}$ is a square.

[image]

The region $\displaystyle \begin{cases}|u|\le 2(2) \\|v|\le 2 \end{cases}$ is a parallelpgram containing the square. It is indeed the smallest parallelogram with sides of such slopes that contains the square.

[image]

The region $\displaystyle \begin{cases}|x|\le3(2) \\|y|\le 2 \end{cases}$ is a rectangular containing the parallelogram. It is the smallest rectangle with vertical and horizontal sides that contains the parallelogram.

[image]

All the points lying inside the square are also in the rectangle. 
There is no mistake. The process is just not reversible.

$\displaystyle \begin{cases}|x|\le3\alpha \\|y|\le \alpha\end{cases}$ does not imply that $\displaystyle \begin{cases}|u|\le 2\alpha \\|v|\le \alpha \end{cases}$, and $\displaystyle \begin{cases}|u|\le 2\alpha \\|v|\le \alpha \end{cases}$ does not imply that $\begin{cases}|x|\le\alpha \\|y|\le \alpha\end{cases}$.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to find a way that the solution can guarantee the reversed side. Can you suggest it?

Comment: As $|x-y|\le \alpha$ give a region bounded by lines with slope $1$, it is impossible to bound exactly the square. If you want to have equivalent constraints, it has to be $|v|\le \alpha$ and $|u+v|\le \alpha$, and of course it is essentially the original constraints.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a mistake to me. The issue is that you arrive at bounds that are not as "tight" as they can be. For example, if I say I'm thinking of a number between $1$ and $5$, and then you ask me if the number is less than $15$, then yes, you'd be right, in every situation. Just because the number I'm thinking of is less than $15$ doesn't mean that every number between $1$ and $5$ is a candidate! It's very similar here. You have a bound on $|x|$ which is $3\alpha$, and given that your original bound is $\alpha$, you're completely correct. It's just not the tightest bound you could give.

The "problem" (and I'm putting problem in quotes here because it's not really a problem but rather why you're getting different answers) comes from adding the "worst case" bounds as if they are independent.

You have that $u = x - y$, $v = y$ and thus $x = (x - y) + y$ and so $x = u + v$. Because the $-y$ and $y$ cancel in the $x$ expression, you'll never have the case where $|(x-y)+y| > \alpha$.

For example, let's take $\alpha = 5$, $x = 5$, $y=-5$. Then you'll have that $u = 10$, which is within the bounds you got for the magnitude, $2\alpha$. However, $x = u + v \Leftrightarrow x = 10 -5 = 5$. But your bound was that this value has to be $\leq 3\alpha$, which is absolutely correct. It's just not the tightest bound you can put, because to get from $u$ to $x$ you are subtracting the  term $y = v$ which you added in the first place to get the value $u$!

More informally, if we're playing a game where you and I both pick a number between $-5$ and $5 = \alpha$, and we add them together and then subtract one of our numbers, this "new" number (let's call it $k$) will be between $-5$ and $5$. But you are getting that it could be up to $15$ ($3\alpha$) because you're not taking into account the fact that the new $k$ is just the inverse of one of the numbers, effectively undoing the change. Your calculations would yield the tightest bound if instead, we brought in a 3rd person and had them subtract a completely new, independent number between $-5$ and $5$ from our sum.

Comment: Yes, thank for your explain. I think so, the bound is not tight. My target is to find bounds of $u,v$ such that it also satisfies the back verification. Could you please suggest it?